# How to auto mount NFS shares on MacOS

Tags: macos, nfs

I want to auto mount some NFS shares from my Synology NAS when I boot my Mac.
Until recently, I had this working:

```
/etc/auto_master:

+auto_master        # Use directory service
/net                -hosts      -nobrowse,hidefromfinder,nosuid
/home               auto_home   -nobrowse,hidefromfinder
/Network/Servers    -fstab
/-                  -static
/-                  auto_nfs    -nobrowse,nosuid


/etc/auto_nfs:

/mnt/idefix/digikam -fstype=nfs,noowners,nolockd,resvport,hard,bg,intr,rw,tcp,nfc,rsize=8192,wsize=8192 nfs://idefix:/volume1/digikam
```

Now, after upgrading to MacOS 10.15 (Catalina) this is no longer working.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe try adding a specific version of the NFS protocol, e.g. `intr,rw,tcp,vers=3` or 2 or 4. Just guessing.

Comment: tried  `vers=2, 3 and 4`, but  makes no difference...

Comment: Oh, well it was worth a try. Maybe try `showmount -e idefix` to see what it's exporting. Also, not sure about the `nfs://` you have in there. Surely it's implicit that it's NFS protocol? I am not sure about this, btw, just guessing some ideas as you seem stuck!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it probably belongs on **Ask Different** Stack Exchange site and is likely to get a better answer there.

Comment: @willemx any update on this question?

Answer (score 6):

Not a direct answer, but in my case I needed to update the mountpoint specified in `/etc/auto_nfs` from `/Users/foo/mountpoint` to `/System/Volumes/Data/Users/foo/mountpoint`. Catalina disk structure has changed directory, perhaps related to your issue.

Comment: You also want to create `/etc/synthetic.conf` to create the mount point next time the mac is rebooted.  It should contain something like `mnt   
 /System/Volumes/Data/mnt`

Comment: updated in `/etc/auto_nfs` from `/Volumes/Pictures  -fstype=nfs,noowners,nolockd,noresvport,hard,bg,intr,rw,tcp,nfc nfs://192.168.0.155/nfs/Pictures` to `/System/Volumes/Data/Pictures  -fstype=nfs,noowners,nolockd,noresvport,hard,bg,intr,rw,tcp,nfc nfs://192.168.0.155/nfs/Pictures` and it resolved the issue. Now my pictures can be found by this path `/System/Volumes/Data/Pictures` which is fine.

Answer (score 3):

Yet another breaking change in a minor update to Catalina (10.15.2). The configuration that worked for me is the following:

```
/etc/auto_master:

#
# Automounter master map
#
+auto_master        # Use directory service
#/net           -hosts      -nobrowse,hidefromfinder,nosuid
/home           auto_home   -nobrowse,hidefromfinder
/Network/Servers    -fstab
/-          -static
/Users/Share        auto_nfs


/etc/auto_nfs:

mntp    -noowners,nolockd,noresvport,hard,bg,intr,rw,tcp,nfc server:/share
```

This will automount the share `server:/share` on `/Users/Share/mntp`.

Comment: Can you enumerate all of the steps involved here in addition to these two configuration files? After you created these 2 files, did you, for example, initiate a `mount /Users/Shared/mntp` as a regular user or with `sudo` or take any other steps? Did you have to `mkdir /Users/Shared/mtp` first?

Comment: Once you've changed the `auto_master` file, run `sudo automount -vc`. The caveat is that every minor/major MacOS update now resets `/etc/auto_master` so one has to add the `/Users/Share...` line by hand. I haven't found a simple way to do this automatically (suggestions welcome!).

Comment: Hmm. It works, but, strangely, the directory permissions show up as read/execute only (although your line clearly mounts the share as read/write). I need to see what is wrong with my setup...

Answer (score 0):

The following post may be of value on this topic:
https://tisgoud.nl/2020/10/persistent-nfs-mount-points-on-macos

See `man fstab` for details in the shell.

> The different fields of an fstab line:
>
> - field 1: fs_spec, the remote filesystem
> - field 2: fs_file, the mountpoint for the filesystem
> - field 3: fs_vfstype, the type of the filesystem
> - field 4: fs_mntops, the mountoptions in a comma separated list

The steps the author outlines are to,

1. edit `/etc/fstab` via `sudo vifs`
2. insert your desired fields, author includes the following example(s):

```
$ cat /etc/fstab
#
# Warning - this file should only be modified with vifs(8)
#
# Failure to do so is unsupported and may be destructive.
#
192.168.200.200:/volume1/calibre /System/Volumes/Data/Nandi/calibre nfs rw,nolockd,resvport,hard,bg,intr,rw,tcp,nfc,rsize=65536,wsize=65536
192.168.200.200:/volume1/docker /System/Volumes/Data/Nandi/docker nfs rw,nolockd,resvport,hard,bg,intr,rw,tcp,nfc,rsize=65536,wsize=65536
192.168.200.200:/volume1/web /System/Volumes/Data/Nandi/web nfs rw,nolockd,resvport,hard,bg,intr,rw,tcp,nfc,rsize=65536,wsize=65536
```

3. trigger the mount points via `sudo automount -cv`
4. check the mount points, example:

```
$ mount
...
map -static on /System/Volumes/Data/Nandi/web (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
map -static on /System/Volumes/Data/Nandi/docker (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
map -static on /System/Volumes/Data/Nandi/calibre (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
```